# How to find if a JToken contains a value?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a value inside a JToken called "Contact_Name". The problem I am having is that it never enters the if statement, I have tried with other values and it never finds them.

```
    RestResponse response = await client.GetAsync(request);
    var results = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
    var array = results["data"].Value<JArray>();
    foreach (var result in array)
                {
                    string _opportunity_description = result.Value<JObject>()["Description"].Value<String>();
                    string opportunity_id = result.Value<JObject>()["id"].Value<String>();
                    string opportunity_closing_date = result.Value<JObject>()["Closing_Date"].Value<String>();
                    string opportunity_closing_date_timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Parse(zoho_opportunity_closing_date).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString();
                    string opportunity_stage = result.Value<JObject>()["Stage"].Value<String>();
                    string opportunity_deal_name = result.Value<JObject>()["Deal_Name"].Value<String>();
                    string opportunity_probability = result.Value<JObject>()["Probability"].Value<String>();
                    string opportunity_account_id = result.Value<JObject>()["Account_Name"].Value<JObject>()["id"].Value<String>();
                    string opportunity_deal_owner_email = result.Value<JObject>()["Owner"].Value<JObject>()["email"].Value<String>();
                   
                    if (result.Contains("Contact_Name"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("kjlnas");
                        //string opportunity_deal_contact_id = opportunity_deal_contact_name.Value<JObject>()["id"].Value<String>();
                    }  }
```

In postman i have found that Contact_Name can have two cases:
First one:

```
"data": [
        {
            "Contact_Name" : null
        }]
```

Second case:

```
"data": [
            {
                "Contact_Name" :{
                      "id": xxx,
                      "name": xxx}
            }]
```

Answer (score 2):

try following way it may help I am not sure about it

```
If(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Value<JObject>()["Contact_Name"].Value<String>()))
{
 //Your Logic 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
if (result.SelectToken("Contact_Name") != null)
{
  // Process data
}
```